# retrieve column value based on column value in another table

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I have two tables:

- Tbl 1
- Tbl 2

`Tbl 2` contains transactions performed by users in `Tbl 1`. Tables contain data like following screenshorts.

[image: Tbl 1]   -    [image: Tbl 2]

I want to select data from `Tbl 2` but instead of `ac_to` column value I want its corresponding `uid` value from `Tbl 1`.

My query trails are:

```
select t2.ac_from_ui,
       t1.ui as "ac_to_uid",
       t2.amt
from tbl1 t1
join tbl2 t2
on t2.ac_to = t1.ac_ref
```

So there are two things I want to find out:

- Is there any better way to query and get data from other table based on value in one table
- Using above query make me lose transactions with **NA** in the `ac_to` field. I want to keep those

*I tried left join, but its performance on huge dataset is issue for me*

Comment: A left join shouldn't have that great am impact. Is this a casting or indexing issue?

Comment: no, is leftjoin will be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What's the dataype of these columns? Is there a large precentage of NA rows? Check Explain if tbl_2 is *redistributed*.

Comment: They are partitioned on datetime, and yes there are huge number of NA rows

Comment: Again, what's the datatype of those columns?  A string `'NA'` and a numeric '5' don't match.

Comment: @dnoeth both as varchar

Comment: You might split into UNIONed selects, adding `where t2.ac_to = 'NA'` to #1 and `where t2.ac_to = 'NA'` to #2. Btw, if there are statistics on t2.ac_to the optimizer should apply this technique automatically to avoid skew.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the standard or classical approach to do this. A left join would keep the tuples with 'NA' in the response. Do you have appropriate indexes on your tables?